# Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction;nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException:Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, amazon-rds

I am learning how to use Hibernate and Spring JPA for a website. While trying to check and add data to a MySql database in AWS RDS by using Postman. But when I am accessing the URI I am receiving 500 Internal Server. Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Error Stack:

```
"org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:467)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:595)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:382)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)\r\n\tat jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy102.save(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat com.example.FootballPred.serviceImp.ClubFootballServiceImp.addTeam(ClubFootballServiceImp.java:18)\r\n\tat com.example.FootballPred.controller.ClubFootballController.addTeam(ClubFootballController.java:21)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)\r\nCaused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection\r\n\tat org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:48)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:111)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:138)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:276)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:284)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:246)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:83)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:164)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:421)\r\n\t... 64 more\r\nCaused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30097ms.\r\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:696)\r\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:197)\r\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:162)\r\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:38)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:108)\r\n\t... 71 more\r\nCaused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:73)\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setNetworkTimeout(ConnectionImpl.java:2485)\r\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.setNetworkTimeout(PoolBase.java:566)\r\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.isConnectionAlive(PoolBase.java:173)\r\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:186)\r\n\t... 76 more\r\nCaused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ConnectionIsClosedException: No operations allowed after connection closed.\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:483)\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.checkClosed(NativeSession.java:761)\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:568)\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setNetworkTimeout(ConnectionImpl.java:2481)\r\n\t... 79 more\r\n",

"message": "Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection",
```

These are the below files:

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://database-1.cogwxhggkept.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/Football
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=user
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

## Hibernate Properties
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

ClubFootballTeamEntity1:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FottballTeamClub")
public class ClubFootballTeamEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "footballTeamId")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "footballTeamName")
    private String teamName;

    @Column(name = "footballTeamNat")
    private String teamNameNat;

    @Column(name = "footballTeamNameAbv")
    private String teamNameAbv;

    public ClubFootballTeamEntity() {
    }

    public ClubFootballTeamEntity(String teamName, String teamNameNat, String teamNameAbv) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
        this.teamNameNat = teamNameNat;
        this.teamNameAbv = teamNameAbv;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTeamName() {
        return teamName;
    }

    public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
    }

    public String getTeamNameNat() {
        return teamNameNat;
    }

    public void setTeamNameNat(String teamNameNat) {
        this.teamNameNat = teamNameNat;
    }

    public String getTeamNameAbv() {
        return teamNameAbv;
    }

    public void setTeamNameAbv(String teamNameAbv) {
        this.teamNameAbv = teamNameAbv;
    }
}
```

ClubFootballController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/clubfootball/v1")
public class ClubFootballController {

    @Autowired
    private ClubFootballService clubFootballService;

    @PostMapping("/addteam")
    public ResponseEntity<ClubFootballTeamEntity> addTeam(@RequestBody ClubFootballTeamEntity team){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(clubFootballService.addTeam(team));
    }

}
```

ClubFootballRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface ClubFootballRepository extends JpaRepository<ClubFootballTeamEntity, Integer> {

}
```

ClubFootballServiceImp:

```
@Service
public class ClubFootballServiceImp implements ClubFootballService {

    @Autowired
    private ClubFootballRepository clubFootballRepository;

    @Override
    public ClubFootballTeamEntity addTeam(ClubFootballTeamEntity team) {
        clubFootballRepository.save(team);
        System.out.println(team.getTeamName());
        return team;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, change:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name
```

to

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was, that in hibernate.properties I've named my url-connection not correct.

hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/project2

but actually it was named 'first_db'

Check it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).